# How to SSH twice using python

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, paramiko

I have 3 hosts:

```
Ipaddresses: hostA = 10.108.190.23 
             hostB = 10.108.190.82
             hostC = 128.221.252.67
```

I can ping `hostB` from `hostA` and `hostC` from `hostB`....There is no direct path from `hostA` to `hostC`

I want to run a script on `hostA` which would start `ntpd daemon` on `hostB` and `hostC` and also transfer some files.

Using `paramiko` I have been able to do that from `hostA` to `hostB` but then I am stuck.
I tried to send a python script to `hostB` which would start the `ntpd daemon` on `hostC` but that didn't work as the pythong script on `hostB` is making an ssh connection using subprocess
module since `paramiko` is not available on `hostB` and I am not allowed to install it either.

Could someone please help me to understand how to perform this double ssh?
Also when I use `paramiko` to connect to remote machine and execute code, does the code get executed on my machine or remote machine?

Comment: This is called "multi-hop ssh"

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH to machine through a middle host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366652/ssh-to-machine-through-a-middle-host), more specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366652/ssh-to-machine-through-a-middle-host/13388479#13388479)

Comment: Use the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472288/python-ssh-password-auth-no-external-libraries-or-public-private-keys/20472419#20472419 and then simply do `ssh 10.0.0.1 'ssh 10.10.0.2 \' ssh 10.20.0.3\''` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since `ssh` will start a *shell* on the remote computer, this task might be easier to solve in *shell* programming than artificially introducing a Python script.  You would end up by using the shell to start your Python script which would only complicate things unnecessarily.

The best solution actually depends on what you want to do.

**Log in on C via B from A**

```
A$ ssh B
B$ ssh C
```

(No surprise here, I'm sure.)

**Start a command on C**

```
A$ ssh B 'ssh C ls'
```

This will start the command `ls` on host C.  It is necessary that the login itself does not query any passwords from the tty.  It is okay if it asks you via a popup window, though.

**Transmit a file from C to A**

```
A$ ssh B 'ssh C "cat /path/to/remotefile"' > /path/to/localfile
```

The same restrictions concerning passwords apply.  Better use proper keys anyway so you can login without being asked for a password.

**Transmit a file from A to C**

```
A$ ssh B 'ssh C "cat > /path/to/remotefile"' < /path/to/localfile
```

And again, password queries might interfere, so get rid of them.