# SSH to server through middle server using python

Tags: python, ssh

I'm trying to do ssh through middle server with python.

I tried to work as written at this example : [SSH to machine through a middle host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19643415/4193208)

but when I'm running the code, I'm getting the following exception `paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner`
When I'm opens the terminal that executes the program password authentication is required in order to proceed

I also edited the `~/.ssh/config` as follows:

```
Host cybnode13
        ProxyCommand  ssh root@cybhead1.lnx.biu.ac.il nc %h %p
```

My code is attached below

```
proxy_command = 'ssh -p %s %s@%s nc %s %s' % (password, proxy_user, proxy_host, host, 22)

proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand(proxy_command)


client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(host, username=proxy_user, password=password, sock=proxy)

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('echo HELLO')
```

Comment: What's your Python version? There was issue https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/673 on Python 3

Comment: @Samuel I'm using python 3.5, but the error exists when I'm using python 2.7 also

Comment: And what is Paramiko  version?

Comment: 2.1.0 for python 2.7 and python 3.5

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29225295/524743) answer helps

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't helps. I made some changes to ~/.ssh/config and update the question details.